# How to get pre-approval key for pre-approval payment in Android using Paypal?

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using Paypal_MPL.jar library in my android app. Simple payment and other payments I have no issue but for pre-approval payment it's asking for pre-approval key.

How to generate pre-approval key through Android code?

Comment: Hi Androiddeveloper,
You got any answer...?If, yes then help me...